# Simulate unplug/replug for USB device on a USB hub on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, command-line-interface

I have a group virtualbox Ubuntu VM's on a Windows host with a powered 10 port USB3 hub attached to it. My VM's are set up in a way that each VM only can see one device on the hub (think android devices). How can I programmatically simulate an unplug/replug of a device on a single VM? I want to restart the USB connection to the port that the VM "owns" without affecting any other VM/port combination in the group.

Unbinding and binding in /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd didn't seem to work. If I plug the device directly into the machine (not through the hub), that approach works.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to affect the device or the VM?  You might be able to configure the VM supervisor to un-forward the device from the VM, causing device unplug processing in the guest OS, but that won't be the same as causing reset/re-enumeration to the device.

Comment: The device. I want the device itself to think it was unplugged and plugged back into the machine. I should add that I was able to unbind the device when connected to the hub, but attempting to bind caused errors that I did not face when the device was directly connected to the machine